# Android Eclipse app deactivate logs in LogCat

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Hey this question has been asked a couple of times already, but is there a way to decrease the amount of logs, Eclipse receives from a device?

I am receiving HUNDREDS of log entries per second, most likely because I am using a china phone in which the debug levels probably haven't been set back before shipping.

All that wouldn't be a problem if filters actually blocked "unwanted" logs. Why? Having my phone attached, eclipse consumes about 130% CPU load which makes working with it awful. The phone is rooted so if I could add any code to my app that blocks all logs except the ones that come out of my app, I'd be pleased. (or maybe, all logs in general)

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I found out that deleting all existing filters has a huge positive influence on the cpu load. Probably the filtering rather than the logging itself consumes so many CPU cycles. Problem still persists tho

Comment: Is there a way in logcat to customize your logcat output? So instead of showing output from `adb logcat`, you could customize it to show output of `adb logcat > /dev/null`? That way nothing would actually get picked up by Eclipse.

Comment: You got me on the right way there. Actually, this is implemented in the LogCat GUI in Eclipse; setting the log level on 'assert' made my CPU usage go down to 15% - thanks man!